# Is it possible to use jquery mobile auto dividers that are based on a custom attribute derived from knockout.js?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, knockout.js

I have the following list which is initially created by knockout.js

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="PromoListDiv">
      <ul id="List" data-bind="foreach: promotions">
       <li data-bind="attr:{'data-status': ApprovalStatus}"><a data-bind="text: Title, attr: {href: ButtonLink}"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- /content -->
```

and here is the code that calls the listview plugin in jquery

```
            $('#List').listview({
            autodividers: true,
            autodividersSelector: function (li) {
                var out = li.attr('ApprovalStatus');
                return out;
            }
        });
```

I had attempted to add a custom attribute to the

elements and have it create the dividers based on that but the list displays (with all data present) without dividers. I think I have all the pieces to do this but I do not understand jquery enough to make use of them, ideally this list would be separated by dividers based on a property of the knockout model. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out why it was not working

```
var out = li.attr('ApprovalStatus');
```

is incorrect as it does not correctly select the list element nor the correct attribute, this does:

```
var out = $(li).attr('data-status');
```